# How to cast if is derived class from a specific base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, casting

I am trying to cast aobject to class if is it derived from another specific class or cast to basic types(int, float string etc..) in template method, but i get same errors.

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//Base class
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    std::string Get() {
        return "A";
    };
};

//Derived class
class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual ~B() = default;
    std::string Get() {
        return "B";
    };
};

class C
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void Echo(T* t)
    {
        if (std::is_base_of<A, T>::value)
        {
            //complex types, derived from A
            std::cout << dynamic_cast<A*>(t)->Get();
        }
        else
        {
            //basic types(int, float, string etc...)
            std::cout << *t;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.Echo(new int(12345));
    c.Echo(new B());

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘t’ (of type ‘int*’) to type ‘class A*’ (source is not a pointer to class)
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘B’)
.
.
.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do something like that, thank you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use C++17 if constexpr:

```
    if constexpr(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value)
    {
        //complex types, derived from A
        std::cout << static_cast<A*>(t)->Get();
    }
    else
    {
        //basic types(int, float, string etc...)
        std::cout << *t;
    }
```

The issue is that even if you know at compile time that T is an `int*`, the classic `if` will still evaluate all branches.

The other option is to use `std::enable_if`, for instance:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, void> Echo(T* t)
{
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<A*>(t)->Get();
}
```

And similar for the other branch.

After a comment, indeed, you know `T` is an `A`, so use `static_cast`.

Comment: Why use a dynamic cast if you know the type can be cast correctly at run time? Use `static_cast`.

Comment: Well, one reason: `static_cast` doesn't play well with virtual base classes, because their location relative to the derived class is not known at compile time. That's not applicable here...